# How to horizontally align <div> inside <td> with components.css?

Tags: html, css

I'm using `components.css` to style this part.

I'm trying to align a `<div>` horizontally inside `<td>`. Look:

```
<td>
    <div class="md-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1)" class="md-check checkboxes" value="147">
        <label for="checkbox1">
            <span></span>
            <span class="check"></span>
            <span class="box"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</td>
```

I saw that the `<div>` with `class="md-checkbox"`, is filling up all the cells. I tried to decrease the `width` (with `!important`), but it didn't work:

[image: table]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="md-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1)" class="md-check checkboxes" value="147">
        <label for="checkbox1">
            <span></span>
            <span class="check"></span>
            <span class="box"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.md-checkbox {
  dipslay: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave inline style to div element in your code as below,

```
 <div class="md-checkbox" style="width:10px">
```

It is reducing the width. Even I tried with changing the width using css file. That approach also works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the css of `components.css` I solve with this:

```
.md-checkbox label {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 9px; 
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```